# amazon Redshift incremental pipeline

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

We are planning to shift to amazon-redshift  for our datawarehousing solution , We have the requirement to setup a incremental pipeline from mysql to redshift  which also handles updates , what is the most efficient methodology to do this  ?

Answer (score 0):

For the data synchronization from MySQL to RedShift, you can try to use AWS Data Pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some existing on the market solution like http://www.bryte.com.au/solutions/amazon-redshift-integration/. Otherwise you will need to implement triggers and AWS Data Pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Periodic background Read from MySQL Tables and writing into Redshift. Here you will create spike load on MySQL DB whenever periodic read is going on. MySQL DB will become slow for other online user at that time.

Option 2:  Use Option 1 but better way, modify MySQL Schema Tables for extra Flags and Columns and let multi-threaded background program read from MySQL Tables in more efficient manner on MySQL Tables.

Option 3: Cost effective way, using S3 as a Staging Area, modify Program that write into MySQL, let that program also write to S3 location. You can run custom java program in backgrounds that will periodically sync from S3 to Redshift.
Going for Data Pipeline will be costly option along with spike load on MySQL DB.

Option 4: [Attunity Cloud Beam](http://www.attunity.com/products/attunity-cloudbeam)

Option 5: AWS Data pipeline

Option 6: AWS lambda function

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping things as simple as possible. If the size of your MySQL db is smallish then you can run `mysqldump`, load each table's dump to a staging table and then do INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE process against the final table. If your MySQL db is too big for regular full dumps then you'll need to do selective extracts of changed data.

We do a hybrid of these 2 approaches (from SQL Server): selective extracts for huge tables which are append only and full dumps of smaller tables where the data is updated. We do this hourly and are able to process hundreds of GBs per day without issue.

Alternatively you can try some of the commercial ETL tools which claim to "synchronise" your database with Redshift (start with Informatica Cloud and Attunity Cloudbeam). We found that these tools couldn't support some of the transforms we need between live and Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following solutions:

1. [AWS Data Pipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-redshiftrdsincremental.html)
2. [Attunity CloudBeam](http://www.attunity.com/products/attunity-cloudbeam)
3. [FlyData](https://www.flydata.com/)

Comment: 4. [ironBeast](http://www.ironsrc.com/ironbeast)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Data Pipeline for this or use [ironBeast](http://www.ironsrc.com/ironbeast). A service that will help you with transferring the data to Redshift and with the maintenance of the data once it's inside (set expiry, Vacuums, fix stl_load_errors and more)

http://www.ironsrc.com/ironbeast

Disclosure: I'm leading a team that develops this solution.